# How to import 2 million of XML files into Postgresql?

Tags: xml, postgresql

I have about 2 million of XML files. I need to extract, index and search on the data. 
I would like to import them in Postgresql: I don't know if this is the best option - probably no - but is a database I know.

I created a very simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE articolo (
    id_articolo BIGSERIAL not null
        constraint articolo_pk
            primary key,
    data xml,
    is_comm boolean default true,
    data_ins timestamp default now()
);
```

A query like this is fine:

```
INSERT INTO articolo (data) 
VALUES (pg_read_file('/home/articoli/comm_use/Psychophysiology/PMC7027463.nxml')::xml);
```

I need an efficient way, because the server use old 7200 HDD and is a bit slow.
Which is the best way to import all the xml files of the /home/articoli/comm_use folder and his subfolder?

Comment: "because the server use old 7200 HDD and is a bit slow"  So then, what are you going to do with them once loaded?  Why struggle to load data to a server which will then struggle to do anythng useful with it?

Comment: I'm studying the logic. After I can decide to move to other server or another architecture. For example I would like also to explore an S3 + Athena solution or similar.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably extract the most important fields from the xml and make them real columns in your table.

But anyway, you certainly don't want to issue an fdatasync for every row inserted, so either combine many rows into one transaction, or set synchronous_commit to off.

If your xml files have no internal tabs, newlines, or backslashes (or you can preprocess them to remove or escape any of those) then you could stream the data into `COPY articolo (data) from STDIN`

Comment: I set the synchronous_commit to off and the performance are have increased significantly. About the structure I think about the virtual, indexed columns. I have experience on this with MySQL, but I think Postgresql has also more options. 
Can you make an example of the COPY usage? 

Thank you